# Use P4 describe to get author and description of a changelist from perforce

Tags: bash, command-line, perforce

I have a changelist number of perforce. How do I get the author and description or this changelist using p4 describe.

I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Did you even attempt to say `p4 help describe`?

Answer (score 0):

p4 describe `changelist#`

Prints:

```
C:\Users\a148530 p4 describe 45
Change 45 by a148530@a148530_CMServices on 2013/03/26 10:34:12

    Added Rally/Perforce integration, as configured, and including logs.
    Not functional in current state.
    These are the files copied verbatim from the Production Perforce
    server.

Affected files ...

I didnt paste this section but it is a list of files and a state (add/delete/etc)
```

Comment: That command produces a load of extra crap when OP clearly stated he only wanted the author and the description. Why doesn't p4 have a sensible way of querying individual fields?